# How to save python luigi terminal output in log file with timestamp in log file name

Tags: python-3.x, logging, luigi

I have a simple luigi pipeline.

```
import luigi
import subprocess
import row_count_test


class TaskOne(luigi.Task):


    def requires(self):
        return None

    def run(self): 
        output = row_count_test()
        if output:
            with self.output().open('w') as open_file:
                open_file.write('{}'.format(output))

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('TaskOne.txt')


class TaskTwo(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        return TaskOne()
    def run(self):
        subprocess.call('rm *.txt', shell = True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    luigi.run()
```

I run the following code through command line:

```
python luigi_demo.py --scheduler-host localhost TaskTwo
```

I want to be able to save the terminal output to a log file. I also want to be able to add a time stamp to the log file name. I know there's a way to do it through bash commands. Is there a way to do this using luigi? I looked at the luigi.cfg documentation and it wasn't too helpful. A simple example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to changes the following to your  TaskTwo.

```
import datetime as dt
class TaskTwo(luigi.Task):
date= luigi.DateSecondParameter(default=dt.datetime.now())

def output(self):
   # Here you create a file  with your date in it.
   return luigi.LocalTarget('path/to/your/log/file%s.txt' % self.date)

def requires(self):
    return TaskOne()

def run(self):
    self.output().open('w') as f:
       subprocess.call('rm *.txt', shell = True,stdout=f)
```

Also, on a side note if you want to delete the file created in the  Taskone then you can remove all the code in the run() then just  add self.input().remove()

```
class TaskTwo(luigi.Task):
date= luigi.DateSecondParameter(default=dt.datetime.now())

def output():
   return luigi.LocalTarget('path/to/your/log/file%s.txt' % self.date)

def requires(self):
    return TaskOne()

def run(self):
    # this should remove the file created in the  Task one.
    self.input().remove()
```